# Python How do I search through a dictionary if the the value is a list and I have the first number in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So if I have a dictionary like

```
    mydict = {"a":[0,0], "b":[2,1], "c":[2,2], "d":[0,0], "e":[3,1]}
```

How would I search for all keys that the first number in its value is 2 (so I get "b" and "c")?

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't place where people write code for you, you need to show that you did research and put effort into solving problem before asking question. So please try to do at least something yourself and then if you still have problem come here to ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
mydict = {"a":[0,0], "b":[2,1], "c":[2,2], "d":[0,0], "e":[3,1]}
final_vals = [a for a, [b, c] in mydict.items() if b == 2]
```

Output:

```
['c', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

First iterate your dict and then verify your 1st element of list using if, here is the one - liner sol using list comprehension

```
mydict = {"a":[0,0], "b":[2,1], "c":[2,2], "d":[0,0], "e":[3,1]}
print([ k for k, v in mydict.items() if v[0]==2])
['c', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to gather the keys as below:

```
mydict = {"a":[0,0], "b":[2,1], "c":[2,2], "d":[0,0], "e":[3,1]}
keys = [key for key, value in mydict.items() if value[0] == 2]
print(keys)
```

Output:

```
['c', 'b']
```